# Load the page upon changes in the database - possible?

Tags: jquery, ajax, database, reload

I'm just wondering if it's possible to reload the current page with jQuery or AJAX, when the database has been changed in some sort? If this is possible, how do I make it reality on my website?

Demonstration of what I mean: Lets say that one visitor is located on the frontpage of the website. The visitor is just idle on the page when I post a new blogpost. The page reloads using jQuery or AJAX when it sees the new blogpost in the database, and show the new post for the visitor. Simliar function to this is `setTimeout()`, but I don't want to stress the server if I have 100 active visitors on the same page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Great question.  I wonder how stackoverflow does it with their 'new answers' update

Comment: Yea! Hopefully we got a answer to this function too

Comment: Certainly possible. Take a look at [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) for example.

Answer (score 1):

Set javascript `var MyItemID = get_file_contents(notice.html)` on page, use `setTimeout()` for request content from `notice.html` and compare result with Your `MyItemID`

Every time, when You update Your DB, get max entry's ID via `mysql_insert_id()` and put it into the `notice.html`.

Pretty easy, yeah? ;)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't let the server push to clients over HTTP on a server event (I might be wrong here), you can use the [SPDY protocol](http://www.chromium.org/spdy/spdy-whitepaper) if your clients support it (I think only the chrome browser does).

So the only thing you can do is check if the latest record is the same as it was on pageload. You have to check with the server each X seconds/minutes.

You could achieve this by doing something like this:

1. upon pagerequest store the ID of the latest record somewhere on the page (hidden input for example).
2. Write a small serverscript to return only the ID of the latest record (plain)
3. Compare them on the client, if they don't match do a full ajax request for the new content

The only thing the server needs to do (each X sec per client) is query the database for the latest record and output it plain. You can also check on the server (more server load) or output it via JSON (also more server load).

I don't think you can do it without those checks.

Answer (score 0):

Set javascript

```
var MyItemID = get_file_contents(notice.html)
```

on page, use `setTimeout()` for request content from `notice.html` and compare result with your `MyItemID`

Every time, when you update your DB, get max entry's ID via `mysql_insert_id()` and put it into the `notice.html`.